# Блок схема для цикла

Tags: c, c++, блок-схема

В общем в универе нужно блок=схемы рисовать к програмамм из лабораторных работ. И я бы лучше сделал в 3 раз больше этих лабораторных работ, чем рисовал эту хрень. И самое главное преподу на код пофиг, главное блок схемы, и придерается очень жёстко.
Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "funcsLib.h"

int main()
{
    int x,a;
    int func;
    double F;
    test_dy G,Y;
    for(;;){
    printf("Vvedite nomer zhelaemoi funcii [1-3] ili 0 dlya vihoda: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&func);
    if(func==0) break;
    switch (func){
    case 1:
        printf("x = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&x);
        printf("a = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&a);
        G = funcG(x,a);
        if(G.valid)
            printf ("G=%lf\n",G.num);
        else
            printf("Vhodnye znachenija ne prinadlezhat oblasti opredelenija funkcii.\n");
    break;
    case 2:
        printf("x = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&x);
        printf("a = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&a);
        F = funcF(x,a);
        printf ("F=%lf\n",F);
    break;
    case 3:
        printf("x = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&x);
        printf("a = ");
        scanf_s("%d",&a);
        Y =  funcY(x,a);
        if(Y.valid)
            printf ("Y=%lf\n",Y.num);
        else
            printf("Vhodnye znachenija ne prinadlezhat oblasti opredelenija funkcii.\n");
    break;
    default:
        printf("Vi dolzhni vvesti cifru ot 1 do 3.\n"); 
    break;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот блок-схема, которая получилась:
[image]

Он забраковал(( Что ему надо - хз, не может объяснить. Помогите, пожалуйста, скажите, что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы лично эту блок-схему также забраковал. В коде есть цикл, а на схеме - нет.  Но если сильно присмотреться, то его видно. Но очень хитро.

Во вторых - по схеме ничего не понятно. Я бы сказал "перестарались с выносками". А то, что 5 связана с началом, это полный ужас. Была бы 1 (ну или на крайний случай ноль) - было бы понятно.

А вот порисовать иногда блок-схемы - полезно. Понимаешь структуру кода. Но правда не для всякого кода так сходу ее нарисуешь.

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажешь ещё где в VISIO можно найти фигуры "Начало,конец цикла" трапеции?

Comment: я не пользуюсь подобными программами для рисования схем. На листике обычно рисую.

Answer (score 1):

Некроответ.

1. Нарисуйте, что делают функции funcF, funcG, funcY или нарисуйте их в блоке "Предопределенный процесс".
2. В "ключе" в Default у вас вывод сообщения на бумагу? Врятли. Используйте "Дисплей".
3. Алгоритм должен быть не зависим от языка программирования. G.Num и т.п. - убрать.
4. Лучше проработать "соединитель".
5. Где ввод данных, то там не правильный блок. Используйте "Ручной ввод".

Это беглый осмотр.

ЕСПД: **http://fmi.asf.ru/library/book/Gost/19003-80-82.html**